# magento2 error like undefined Property on shipping method like canada post

Tags: magento2, error, onestepcheckout, frontend-error, product-weight

Magento2 checkoutcart page error like undefined Property on shipping method like canada post and not Calculated tax

function inside on here **general/locale/weight_unit** like

```
public function getStoreWeightUnit($storeId)
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'general/locale/weight_unit',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $storeId
        ) == 'kbs' ? 'KILOGRAM' : 'GRAM';
    }
```

So give me solution.

Thank You,
Your Faithfully,
Mehul Kanjariya

[image]

Comment: update full error

Comment: Property Undefined

Comment: post that file but removing all the functions only having $_scopeconfig and constructor